# Trying to create a comments section on my website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

Okay, so I'm trying to create a comments section using javascript on my website. So far the tutorials I have looked at are really hard to follow. All I want to know is how I post strings and numbers to a server.This is what I have so far...

I'm having absolutely no joy.I'm using an external javascript file.

so far, here's the HTML:

```
 <form action="#" class="add_comment">

        <label>Name
          <input type="string" name="name">
        </label><br>
        <label>Email
          <input type="string" name="email">
        </label><br>
        <label>Comment
         <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment">
      </form>
```

and here's the Javascript:

```
....bloody nowhere.
```

I am actually using Javascript but it's painfully embarrassing stuff that I've tried to edit from W3schools.com. However, all they have on there is code that is used within the HTML, I need an external Javascript file.

As you can see I'm really struggling. I need the comments, names etc to post to a URL. I'd really like some advice on where I could find material on this stuff. Everything I google comes up with nothing (perhaps because I'm phrasing my questions wrong).

Any tutorial links or perhaps advice from someone handy with Javascript would be amazing.

Comment: This question isn't a good match for SO's Q&A format, but this should help: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Also, I know that I have to POST data to the server and then GET the data from the server to display on the page. I just don't know how!

Answer (score -1):

A simple example of what you want to accomplish would be something along these lines:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        // Create data object
        var data = {};
        data.name = $("#name").val();
        data.email = $("#email").val();
        data.comment = $("#comment").val();
        // The url of your server-side script that handles the post submission
        var url = "http://www.someurl.com/post_comment.php";
        $.POST(url, data)
        .done(function(response){
            // This code executes when the server returns a response
            // Do something with the response like adding the comment to the current list of comments
            // Example (if your response is HTML, better would be a JSON string):
            $("#comments").append(response);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You would have to change your HTML to this:

```
 <form id="form" action="javascript:void('');" class="add_comment">

        <label>Name
          <input id="name" type="string" name="name">
        </label><br>
        <label>Email
          <input id="email" type="string" name="email">
        </label><br>
        <label>Comment
         <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment">
      </form>
```

Note the added id's and action="javascript:void('');"

Comment: Thanks for the response! What does the javascript:void('') do?

Comment: It does nothing. I don't know for sure if action="#" would interfere with this script, but I know for certain void() does not.

Comment: So the ("#form").submit(function(e)  calls the data from the HTML form and posts it when the button is clicked? or am I completely wrong.

Comment: First of all, I should have mentioned that I'm using jQuery in this example, which you should include in the <head> section of your website (see https://code.jquery.com/). What happens here, is that whenever you submit the form (by pressing submit, or pressing Enter), the submit event gets fired (`$("#form").submit()`) which in turn fires the anonymous function inside its parentheses.

Comment: So it cannot be used in an external file?

Comment: Adding <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> anywhere (preferrably the <head> section and before the script I posted) should do the trick.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I think I'm going to figure out how to use a get an post function to do it however, just to fit the sites requirements! Again, thanks a lot!